# GWT Spring Integration - How to do AOP logging?

Tags: spring, gwt, aop, logging

I have a GWT application where its RPC services are handled by a GWTHandler bean so that it can integrate with Spring smoothly. The application works. No problem with that.

My issue is I can't do any AOP logging with Spring. I like to log user activities from the GWT interface using AOP. (I could of course do it the old way of calling an RPC service for every action that a user does and log those action, but that is not the AOP way). I have to do it in AOP because that's the client's requirements.

I tried using the normal Spring AOP with a generic pointcut pattern "execution(* *.*(..))". It's able to capture all methods except for the GWT services. So in other words, it's useless.  I could of course log the backend Spring DAO's using AOP but how do I know which RPC service it came from? These DAO's are used by numerous classes and methods (not exclusive to GWT).

I tried exploring GWT-ENT package. It looks good. However, it works on the client's side and your classes must implement Aspectable. This means requiring changes on all client classes on my GWT application. Furthermore, you can't use private methods since to handle AOP with GWT-ENT, you need to create your classes via GWT.create instead of the new(). Having private methods throws an error. I set-up a simple application and really private methods don't work.

I tried searching the GWT-SL package (where my GWTHandler came from). They mentioned about something about AOP, but the info is very scarce. Google didn't give me any solutions or examples.

I've tried everything I could think of and searched Google with all my efforts but I can't find a solution to my problem.

All I want to do is log methods from my GWT services via AOP. Let's say a client goes to the Report tab. Then he click on Delete button record. I want to log that activity via AOP.

I'm using GWT (with SmartGWT) and Spring/Hibernate stack.

Comment: After some investigating, I decided to do the AOP logging in the DAO layer instead of the GWT (presentation/service layer) since we don't care what visual button the user chooses to delete a record. If he deletes a record, it will only use a specific DAO. So it makes sense to AOP log the DAO layer. Furthermore, I realized that another reason why I'm having difficulty is because the previous programmer who handled the project I'm working with has mixed the service and the DAO layers. There should be clean separation between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Spring AOP will only advise public methods of beans in your Spring context, so GWT infrastructure is out unless you specifically instantiate it through the Spring container.

You could use compile-time weaving with AspectJ to wire your AOP into everything, but it might get a bit messy.  It's also uncertain that it would work, unless you are compiling the GWT classes in question.

Comment: The GWT services are Spring beans which are wired up by a 3rd-party class (GWTHandler, similar with Spring's SimpleURLHandler - forgot the exact name). Right now, I'm re-evaluating where the AOP logging should take place. I think it's best that I just log the DAOs instead of the GWT services (since it's next to impossible to log them). I'll reply again once everything becomes clear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna answer my question.

Instead of performing AOP logging on the GWT server implementations (which theoretically should work but in practice it's not), I decided to do AOP logging on the DAO layer. Just make sure you log the DAO not the Hibernate Session